# Recognize text from image (Emgu) issue

Tags: vb.net, image, text, extract, emgucv

i'm using Emgu to extract string from an image but i facing a problem in the last step (Recognize), please help me guys ..

I TYPED THE PROBLEM MESSAGE IN THE CODE AS A COMMENT

code:

```
Imports Emgu.CV
Imports Emgu.Util
Imports Emgu.CV.OCR
Imports Emgu.CV.Structure
    
Public Class Form1
    Dim OCRz As Tesseract = New Tesseract("tessdata", "eng", OcrEngineMode.Default)
    Dim pic As Bitmap = New Bitmap(270, 100)
    Dim gfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(pic)
        
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    gfx.CopyFromScreen(New Point(Me.Location.X + PictureBox1.Location.X + 4, Me.Location.Y + PictureBox1.Location.Y + 30), New Point(0, 0), pic.Size)
    PictureBox1.Image = pic
    PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
End Sub
        
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim img As New Image(Of Bgr, Byte)(pic)   'try another way to solve the problem
        
    OCRz.Recognize(pic)   'not work: Too many arguments to 'Public Function Recognize() As Integer.
    OCRz.Recognize(img)   'not work: Too many arguments to 'Public Function Recognize() As Integer.
    OCRz.Recognize(New Image(Of Bgr, Byte)(pic))   'not work: Overload resolution failed because of no accessible_
    'New' can be called with these arguments.
                        
'Public Sub New(channels() As Emgu.CV.Image(Of Emgu.CV.Structure.Gray, Byte))' Value of type Bitmap cannot_
be converted to 1-dimensional array of Emgu.CV.Image(Of Emgu.CV.Structure.Gray, Byte.
        
    RichTextBox1.Text = OCRz.GetBoxText
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Now it’s work, thanks a lot .. i used an old method with a new version, that was the problem .. thank you again .

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what version you're using.

Try the following:

```
    ...

OCRz.SetImage(img)
OCRz.Recognize()

    ...
```